# Relation GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Trying to implement `join` but always getting `null`.

```
type User {
    id: Int!
    username: String!
    recipes: [Recipe]
  }

  type Recipe {
    id: Int!
    title: String!
    author: User
  }
```

So basically i want to get data something like this:

```
User { 
  username,
  recipes: [{//recipe}, {//recipe}]
}
```

And for Recipe i expecting

```
Recipe {
  title,
  author: {//user}  
}
```

So i have query like below, and i want to get all recipes from database with included user

```
type Query {
    recipes: [Recipe!]!
  }
```

***Here is my GraphiQL query***

```
{
  recipes {
    id,
    author {
      id,
      username
    }
  }
}
```

But in response i have `author: null`

```
{
  "data": {
    "recipes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "author": null
      }]
   }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: The issue is most likely with your resolver, not your query. Please update your question to include your resolver code.

Comment: @DanielRearden, yeah it was issue with resolver 
Thanks for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe somebody will face with similar issue. 
Have fixed this. As said @Daniel Rearden in comments - yes issue was in resolver.

So you have to add this fields to resolver:

```
const resolverFunctions = {
  User: {
      recipes(author) {
        return author.getRecipes();
      }
    },
  Recipe: {
      author(recipe) {
        return recipe.getUser();
      }
    }
}
```

After you will get data what i needed above.